# How to use Grouped SelectListItem mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Hi I trying to get a dropdownlist grouped

in controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> item;
        item = new List<GroupedSelectListItem> {
                    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "volvo", Text = "Volvo", GroupName = "Swedish Cars", GroupKey = "1", Disabled = true },
                    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "saab", Text = "Saab",GroupName = "Swedish Cars", GroupKey = "1" },
                    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "mercedes", Text = "Mercedes", GroupName = "German Cars", GroupKey = "2" },
                    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "audi", Text = "Audi", GroupName = "German Cars", GroupKey = "2",Selected = true }};
        ViewBag.item  = item;
        return View();
    }
```

and in the view

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="class_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Classe</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">

    @Html.DropDownGroupList("Cars", ViewBag.item, "-- Select Car --", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "The Car field is required." } })

         </div
```

I'm trying to pass the IEnumerable to the view with viewbag 
but it not working 
I'm new in .net programing thank you

Comment: What is `GroupedSelectListItem`? and `Html.DropDownGroupList()` - they are not part of MVC. What plugin are you using? And your passing it using `ViewBag` which is dynamic so you need to cast it - `(IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem>)ViewBag.item`

Comment: I'm using this plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/DropDownList.Optgroup.MVC/

Comment: Here is a sample http://bhaumikpatel.github.io/DDL.optgroup.MVC.Demo/

Comment: @mww yes this is the exmple i followed but they call a static data in the view modal 
but I have a dynamic data that I must passed from the controller to the view

Comment: You need to cast it as per the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

It simple just add model and use it like this

Index.cshtml

```
@model IList<GroupedSelectListItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownGroupList("Cars",Model, "-- Select Car --", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-val", "true" }, { "data-val-required", "The Car field is required." } })

}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var item = new List<GroupedSelectListItem> {
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "volvo", Text = "Volvo", GroupName = "Swedish Cars", GroupKey = "1", Disabled = true },
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "saab", Text = "Saab",GroupName = "Swedish Cars", GroupKey = "1" },
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "mercedes", Text = "Mercedes", GroupName = "German Cars", GroupKey = "2" },
    new GroupedSelectListItem() { Value = "audi", Text = "Audi", GroupName = "German Cars", GroupKey = "2",Selected = true }};
        return View(item);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {


        return View();
    }

}
```